# Python Sqlite3 and QSqlite difference

Tags: python, database, sqlite, pyqt

I am trying to create a GUI app with PyQt that will fetch user input and store in a local hard drive. After reading through, I realized that python has it's own built in `sqlite` module and PyQt also provides the `Qsqlite` module but I am not sure which `sqlite` module to use.

1. What is the difference between python's built in `sqlite3` module and PyQt4's `Qsqlite`module?
2. Even though I can find a lot of tutorials for python's built in `sqlite3` module, I can't seems to find good `Qsqlite` documentation. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you planning to combine Qt widgets and data, e.g., displaying a database table in a `QTableView`?

Comment: @CL. I haven't decided which widget to use but most likely will be qtable widget or qtable view.. I am a beginner so I don't have much knowledge over the difference between these two widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The difference is that the Python `sqlite3` use the Python database API, while the Qt `Sqlite` module uses the Qt database API.
   You have to determine which API you want to use, or which one is required by other components in your app.
2. `Qsqlite` is the internal name of Qt's SQLite driver; to actually access it, you would use the normal [Qt database API](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/database.html).

Comment: do you mind explaining in more beginner friendly way? I will be using the database to store the information like name,address and contacts then display it back to the user when requested. Since my GUI was written in PyQt, does it make more sense to use Qsqlite?

Comment: If you will use any of the Qt widgets with direct database support (like `QSqlTableModel`), you should use Qt SQL.